# I want to use Date as my x value in my xyline graph in jaspersoft but it only allow a Number

Tags: jasper-reports, jaspersoft-studio

Is there a way to be able to render a date value instead of a number in jaspersoft XYLine graph? Is there a way to manipulate the x labels so it will display as MM/DD? This is my code right now where I am getting the month and day values and concatenating them as string then converting them as Integer (922, 923, 924, 925). I am also attaching the preview.

```
<xyDataset>
  <xySeries autoSort="true">
    <seriesExpression><![CDATA["SERIES 1"]]></seriesExpression>
    <xValueExpression><![CDATA[Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf($F{date}.getMonth()) +      String.valueOf($F{date}.getDate()))]]></xValueExpression>
    <yValueExpression><![CDATA[$F{temp}]]></yValueExpression>
  </xySeries>
</xyDataset>
```

[image: xyline graph]

Comment: Try this: new SimpleDateFormat("MM dd").format($F{date}) in xValueExpression.

Comment: that doesn't work, too... the resulting value is String...thanks anyway...

Comment: You can try time series graph for this purpose.